# Указатель на внешний объект

Tags: c++

В с++ при  создании деревьев часто используются вложенные структуры типа

```
struct Node {
    struct *Node;
}
```

Как для объекта такой структуры определить указатель на внешний объект, зная только указатель на внутренний?

Comment: Что такое "внешний объект"? Указатель может указывать на что угодно нужного типа, вопрос не понянен.

Comment: Я имею ввиду instance of external class. Т.е. создан объект `Node a`. А потом `Node *c=a.b`. Каким образом, зная `с`, узнать а?

Comment: Напишите в коде чего именно хочется.

Comment: Котд в вопросе пишите, тут в комментах не получится :(

Comment: скорее всего поможет offsetof, по нему можно вычислить смещение поля b в объекте, а потом просто вычесть. Но это будет жуткий костыль.  Обычно проще добавить ещё одну ссылку в объект.

Comment: Судя по юзкейсу что-то не так с логикой работы со списком :) При правильной организации дела такого желания возникать не должно в принципе.

Comment: @klopp,    `#define container_of(ptr, type, member) 
 ((type *)((char *)(ptr)-(unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))` часто используют в Linux (например, в  известном [/linux/include/linux/list.h](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/list.h))

Comment: Нет, конечно, нечто подобное и я использую, но только в низкоуровневых вещах.  И тогда, когда речь идёт о заведомо и точно известном смещении, а не об определении по произвольному члену структуры. А уж этот список образцом для подражания мне считать трудно... Начиная с перегруженности функциналом и заканчивая трудно читаемой кашой из макросов в исходниках. Впрочем, это всего лишь IMHO :-)

Comment: @Jonny937: Если вам нужно "по `c` узнать `a`", то так и пишите в вопросе. То, что написано в вашем вопросе сейчас, даже отдаленно не приближается к тому, что вы, как оказалось, хотели спросить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Я имею ввиду instance of external class. Т.е. создан объект Node a. А потом Node *c=a.b. Каким образом, зная с, узнать а?

Используйте двусвязный принцип - будете хранить как "ветки", так и родителя узла.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int counter = 0;
struct Node
{
    Node* parent;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    int value;
    Node( Node* p ) : Node(p, nullptr, nullptr)
    {

    }
    Node( Node* p, Node* l, Node* r )
    {
        parent = p;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        value = counter++;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node* main = new Node( nullptr, nullptr, nullptr );
    main->left = new Node( main );
    main->right = new Node( main );

    Node* myLeft = main->left;
    myLeft->left = new Node( myLeft );

    cout << main->value << endl;
    cout << main->left->value << endl;
    cout << main->right->value << endl;
    cout << main->left->left->value << endl;

    Node* c = main->left->left;

    cout << c->parent->value << endl; // зная с достучались до a, a.b и a.value легко

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для исходной структуры - никак. Совсем никак. Надо либо строить алгоритмы таким образом. чтобы это не мешало - либо делать так, как предложил rikimaru2013

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то никаких проблем тут нет (по крайней мере для обычных Сишных струтур).

Возможно этот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
  ((type *)((char *)(ptr)-(unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))

struct Node {
  struct Node *node;
};

struct Data {
  int a, b, c;
  struct Node link;
};

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  struct Node *list;
  struct Data *d;

  list = &(((struct Data *)calloc(sizeof(*d), 1))->link);
  d = container_of(list, struct Data, link.node);
  d->a = 1;
  d->b = 2;

}
```

чем-то Вам поможет.